# How can I do test setup using the testing package in Go

Tags: unit-testing, go

How can I do overall test setup processing which sets the stage for all the tests when using the [testing package](http://golang.org/pkg/testing/)?

As an example in Nunit there is a `[SetUp]` attribute.

```
[TestFixture]
public class SuccessTests
{
  [SetUp] public void Init()
  { /* Load test data */ }
}
```

Answer (score 287, accepted):

Starting with Go 1.4 you can implement setup/teardown (no need to copy your functions before/after each test). The documentation is outlined [here](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) in the **Main** section:

> TestMain runs in the main goroutine and can do whatever setup and
>   teardown is necessary around a call to m.Run. It should then call
>   os.Exit with the result of m.Run

It took me some time to figure out that this means that if a test contains a function `func TestMain(m *testing.M)` then this function will be called instead of running the test. And in this function I can define how the tests will run. For example I can implement global setup and teardown:

> ```
> func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
>     setup()
>     code := m.Run() 
>     shutdown()
>     os.Exit(code)
> }
> ```

A couple of other examples [can be found here](http://cs-guy.com/blog/2015/01/test-main/).

> The TestMain feature added to Go’s testing framework in the latest
>   release is a simple solution for several testing use cases. TestMain
>   provides a global hook to perform setup and shutdown, control the
>   testing environment, run different code in a child process, or check
>   for resources leaked by test code. Most packages will not need a
>   TestMain, but it is a welcome addition for those times when it is
>   needed.

Comment: How are you supposed to pass context from the setup function to the tests without using global variables ? For example if mySetupFunction() creates a temporary directory to perform testing in (with a unique, random name), how do the tests know the name of the directory ? There must be a place to set this context ??

Comment: It seems that this is official way to handle before and after hooks for tests, see https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main for official documentation

Comment: @InancGumus `lstat $GOROOT/subtests: no such file or directory`

Comment: please note that ' code := m.Run() ' is the one that runs other TestFunctions !

Comment: @InancGumus not even that, but you have to put it into the very test file where it should apply. So you're not even allowed to split your tests into multple files and put the `TestMain` into an own file in the same package. So "complex" might not be the appropriate term ... even simple structuring is too much.

Comment: @InancGumus that link is dead

Comment: @NotX I tried the `TestMain` solution in Go 1.18 on a package level: I put the TestMain function into its dedicated `main_test.go`, and it seems to be working for tests in multiple other test files. Perhaps they fixed this behavior.

Comment: It is not clear in the answer whether the setup/teardown runs for each test function or runs just once for the package.

Comment: @Lqueryvg Since the `Run` function takes a name and a function that takes a single parameter, you can define an anonymous function that takes just the pointer to testing.T, and in the body of that anonymous function, call any function you want, with the pointer and any additional context you wish:
`t.Run("SubtestA", func(t *testing.T) { SubtestA(t, context_for_subtestA) })` or 
`t.Run("SubtestB", func(t *testing.T) { SubtestB(t, context_for_subtestB) })`

Answer (score 83):

This can be achieved by putting a `init()` function in the `myfile_test.go` file.  This will be run before the `init()` function.

```
// myfile_test.go
package main

func init() {
     /* load test data */
}
```

The myfile_test.init() will be called before the package init() function.

Comment: I know you're answering your own question so this probably satisfies your own use case, but this isn't equivalent to the NUnit example you've included in your question.

Comment: Well @james, I have shown one thought on way to answer the issue and others have already provided some good insights, including yours. Its useful to get outside influences to tune ones approach. Thanks.

Comment: Fair enough.  What you've shown in this answer is somewhat closer to using NUnit's `[TestFixtureSetUp]` attribute instead.

Comment: it does not include tear down part

Comment: This is not a good solution if your test file is in the same package with main function.

Comment: the `_test.go` file is ignored by the build tool, do not start with an underscore. The statement might be misleading to somebody who's starting out.

Comment: Did you make a mistake? It says that the `init()` function will be run before the `init()` function, which I would imagine is not possible in the first place, but I suspect you meant to say before any of the test functions?

Comment: @AlexisWilke I read this as the `myfile_test.go` `init()` will run before `myfile.go`'s `init()`—that is, the test init will run before the package init

Comment: I have included a `init` inside `file_test.go` as well as `file.go`, and the one in `file.go` gets called first. I don't think this is correct. (Both my files are in the same package)

Answer (score 56):

Given a simple function to unit test:

```
package math

func Sum(a, b int) int {
    return a + b
}
```

You can test it with a setup function that returns teardown function. And after calling setup() you can make a deferred call to teardown().

```
package math

import "testing"

func setupTestCase(t *testing.T) func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Log("setup test case")
    return func(t *testing.T) {
        t.Log("teardown test case")
    }
}

func setupSubTest(t *testing.T) func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Log("setup sub test")
    return func(t *testing.T) {
        t.Log("teardown sub test")
    }
}

func TestAddition(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        name     string
        a        int
        b        int
        expected int
    }{
        {"add", 2, 2, 4},
        {"minus", 0, -2, -2},
        {"zero", 0, 0, 0},
    }

    teardownTestCase := setupTestCase(t)
    defer teardownTestCase(t)

    for _, tc := range cases {
        t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            teardownSubTest := setupSubTest(t)
            defer teardownSubTest(t)

            result := Sum(tc.a, tc.b)
            if result != tc.expected {
                t.Fatalf("expected sum %v, but got %v", tc.expected, result)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Go testing tool will report the logging statements in the shell console:

```
% go test -v
=== RUN   TestAddition
=== RUN   TestAddition/add
=== RUN   TestAddition/minus
=== RUN   TestAddition/zero
--- PASS: TestAddition (0.00s)
    math_test.go:6: setup test case
    --- PASS: TestAddition/add (0.00s)
        math_test.go:13: setup sub test
        math_test.go:15: teardown sub test
    --- PASS: TestAddition/minus (0.00s)
        math_test.go:13: setup sub test
        math_test.go:15: teardown sub test
    --- PASS: TestAddition/zero (0.00s)
        math_test.go:13: setup sub test
        math_test.go:15: teardown sub test
    math_test.go:8: teardown test case
PASS
ok      github.com/kare/go-unit-test-setup-teardown 0.010s
%
```

You can pass some additional parameters to setup/teardown with this approach.

Comment: Now that is a real simple but effective trick.  Great use of Go syntax.

Comment: Yeah, but it increases nestedness (_kind of pyramid of doom in javascript_). And, tests do not run automatically by the suite as in the outer tests.

Comment: other problem is tearDown func can not get data of each case, and do the clean up thing base on test result

Answer (score 29):

With the following template, you can make a one line call in each TestMethod that does both setup and tear-down.

```
func setupTest() func() {
    // Setup code here

    // tear down later
    return func() {
        // tear-down code here
    }
}

func TestMethod(t *testing.T) {
    defer setupTest()()
    // asserts, ensures, requires... here
}
```

Comment: This is the greatest answer in this thread

Answer (score 16):

The Go testing framework doesn't have anything equivalent to NUnit's [SetUp attribute](http://nunit.org/docs/2.2.10/setup.html) (marking a function to be called before each test in the suite).  There are a few options though:

1. Simply call your `SetUp` function from each test where it is needed.
2. Use an extension to Go's testing framework that implements xUnit paradigms and concepts. Three strong options come to mind:

   - [gocheck](http://labix.org/gocheck)
   - [testify](https://github.com/stretchr/testify#suite-package)
   - [gunit](https://github.com/smartystreets/gunit)

Each of these libraries encourage you to organize your tests into suites/fixtures similar to other xUnit frameworks, and will call the setup methods on the suite/fixture type before each of the `Test*` methods.

Answer (score 12):

Typically, tests in go aren't written in the same style as other languages. Often, there's relatively fewer test functions, but each contains a table-driven set of test cases. See [this article written by one of the Go team.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/TableDrivenTests)

With a table-driven test, you simply put any setup code before the loop that executes the individual test-cases specified in the table, and put any cleanup code afterwards.

If you still have shared setup code between test functions, you can extract the shared setup code into a function, and use a `sync.Once` if it's important that it's executed exactly once (or as another answer suggests, use `init()`, but this has the disadvantage that the setup will be done even if the test cases aren't run (perhaps because you've limited the test cases by using `go test -run <regexp>`.)

I'd say if you think you need shared setup between different tests that gets executed exactly once you should have a think if you really need it, and if a table-driven test wouldn't be better.

Comment: That's great when testing trivial things like a flag parser, or an algorithm that churns on numbers. But it doesn't really help when trying to test diverse pieces of functionality that all require similar boilerplate code. I suppose I could define my test functions in an array and iterate over those, but then it's not really table-driven so much as a simple loop that should really just be built into the testing framework itself (in the form of a proper test suite with setup/teardown functions)

Answer (score 6):

In case someone is looking an alternative of @BeforeEach (which runs before each test in a test file) and @AfterEach (which runs after test in a test file), here's a helper snippet.

```go
func CreateForEach(setUp func(), tearDown func()) func(func()) {
    return func(testFunc func()) {
        setUp()
        testFunc()
        tearDown()
    }
}
```

You can use it like below with help of TestMain

```go
var RunTest = CreateForEach(setUp, tearDown)

func setUp() {
   // SETUP METHOD WHICH IS REQUIRED TO RUN FOR EACH TEST METHOD
   // your code here
}

func tearDown() {
  // TEAR DOWN METHOD WHICH IS REQUIRED TO RUN FOR EACH TEST METHOD
  // your code here
}

fun TestSample(t *testing.T) {
  RunTest(func() {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
  })
}
```

also you can check: [go-beforeeach](https://github.com/jknair0/beforeeach)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [testing package](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) for test *setup* - which will set the stage for all tests and *teardown* - which will cleanup the stage after tests have run.

The below calculates the area of a rectangle:

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

func area(height float64, width float64) (float64, error) {
    if height == width {
        fmt.Printf("Rectangle with given dimension is a square. Area is: %f\n", height * width)
        return height * width, nil
    } else if height <= 0 || width <= 0 {
        return 0, errors.New("Both dimensions need to be positive")
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("Area is: %f\n", height * width)
        return height * width, nil
    }
}

func main() {
    var length float64  = 4.0
    var breadth float64 = 5.0
    area(length, breadth)
}
```

This is the implementation for test setup and teardown using `TestMain` as Salvador Dali's [explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34102842/13055097). (**Note** that since v1.15 the `TestMain` function is no longer required to call `os.Exit` [[ref](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.15#testing)])

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "testing"
)

var length float64
var breadth float64

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    setup()
    m.Run() 
    teardown()
}

func setup() {
    length = 2.0
    breadth = 3.0
    log.Println("\n-----Setup complete-----")
}

func teardown() {
    length = 0
    breadth = 0
    log.Println("\n----Teardown complete----")
}

func TestAreaOfRectangle(t *testing.T) {
    val, err := area(length, breadth)   
    want := 6.0

    if val != want && err != nil {
        t.Errorf("Got %f and %v; Want %f and %v", val, err, want, nil)
    }
}
```

And this is the implementation for test setup and teardown using sub-tests:

```
package main

import "testing"

func TestInvalidRectangle(t *testing.T) {
    // setup
    var length float64 = -2.0
    var breadth float64 = 3.0
    t.Log("\n-----Setup complete for invalid rectangle-----")

    // sub-tests
    t.Run("invalid dimensions return value", func(t *testing.T) {
        val, _ := area(length, breadth)
        area := 0.0

        if val != area {
            t.Errorf("Got %f; Want %f", val, area)
        }
    })

    t.Run("invalid dimensions message", func(t *testing.T) {
        _, err := area(length, breadth)
        want := "Both dimensions need to be positive"

        if err.Error() != want {
            t.Errorf("Got error: %v; Want error: %v", err.Error(), want)
        }
    })

    // teardown
    t.Cleanup(func(){
        length = 0
        breadth = 0
        t.Log("\n----Teardown complete for invalid rectangle----")
    })
}

func TestRectangleIsSquare(t *testing.T) {
    var length float64 = 3.0
    var breadth float64 = 3.0
    t.Log("\n-----Rectangle is square setup complete-----")

    t.Run("valid dimensions value and message", func(t *testing.T) {
        val, msg := area(length, breadth)
        area := 9.0
        if val != area && msg != nil {
            t.Errorf("Got %f and %v; Want %f and %v", val, msg, area, nil)
        }
    })

    t.Cleanup(func(){
        length = 0
        breadth = 0
        t.Log("\n----Rectangle is square teardown Complete----")
    })
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Shameless plug, I created https://github.com/houqp/gtest to help solve exactly this problem.

Here is a quick example:

```golang
import (
  "strings"
  "testing"
  "github.com/houqp/gtest"
)

type SampleTests struct{}

// Setup and Teardown are invoked per test group run
func (s *SampleTests) Setup(t *testing.T)      {}
func (s *SampleTests) Teardown(t *testing.T)   {}
// BeforeEach and AfterEach are invoked per test run
func (s *SampleTests) BeforeEach(t *testing.T) {}
func (s *SampleTests) AfterEach(t *testing.T)  {}

func (s *SampleTests) SubTestCompare(t *testing.T) {
  if 1 != 1 {
    t.FailNow()
  }
}

func (s *SampleTests) SubTestCheckPrefix(t *testing.T) {
  if !strings.HasPrefix("abc", "ab") {
    t.FailNow()
  }
}

func TestSampleTests(t *testing.T) {
  gtest.RunSubTests(t, &SampleTests{})
}
```

You can create as any test group you want within a package with each of them using a different set of setup/teardown routines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the minimal test suit framework to run subtests with

- `BeforeAll`, ran before all subtests in a test
- `BeforeEach`, ran before each subtest
- `AfterEach`, ran after each subtest
- `AfterAll`, ran after all subtests in a test

```golang
package suit

import "testing"

func Of(subTests *SubTests) *SubTests {
    if subTests.AfterAll != nil {
        subTests.T.Cleanup(subTests.AfterAll)
    }
    return subTests
}

type SubTests struct {
    T          *testing.T
    BeforeEach func()
    AfterEach  func()
    AfterAll   func()
}

func (s *SubTests) TestIt(name string, f func(t *testing.T)) {
    if s.AfterEach != nil {
        defer s.AfterEach()
    }
    if s.BeforeEach != nil {
        s.BeforeEach()
    }
    s.T.Run(name, f)
}
```

**Usage**

```golang
func TestFoo(t *testing.T) {
    // BeforeAll setup goes here

    s := suit.Of(&suit.SubTests{
        T:          t,
        BeforeEach: func() { ... },
        AfterEach:  func() { ... },
        AfterAll:   func() { ... },
    })

    s.TestIt("returns true", func(t *testing.T) {
        assert.Equal(t, 1, 1)
    })
}
```