# setup and teardown for each test using std testing package

Tags: unit-testing, go

I am using go "testing" package. Running my tests like below.

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {

   ...
   // Setup
   os.Exit(m.Run())
   // Teardown
}
```

This will run a setup before any test is run, and a teardown after all tests are complete. And I do need this, as the setup sets the DB up. But also, I need, and yet to find out a way to run a per-test setup/teardown. For the unit tests I am running, I would like to clear the DB before every test, so that there are no issues with the content of the DB causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: looks like this solution might help to run setup and teardown for each tests https://stackoverflow.com/a/65428147/3779042

Answer (score 41, accepted):

[Update for Go 1.14](https://tip.golang.org/doc/go1.14#testing) (Q1 2020)

The `testing` package now supports cleanup functions, called after a test or benchmark has finished, by calling [`T.Cleanup`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/testing#T.Cleanup) or [`B.Cleanup`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/testing#B.Cleanup) respectively. Example,

```
func TestFunction(t *testing.T) {
    // setup code
    t.Cleanup(func(){
        // tear-down code
    })
    // sub-tests
    t.Run() 
    t.Run() 
    ...
}
```

Here, t.Cleanup runs after the test and all its sub-tests are complete.

---

Original answer (Feb. 2017)
As shown in the article "[Go unit test setup and teardown](https://blog.karenuorteva.fi/go-unit-test-setup-and-teardown-db1601a796f2#.2aherx2z5)" from [Kare Nuorteva](https://twitter.com/KareNuorteva), you could use a setup function which returns... a teardown function to you defer.

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kare/ec85d88b9b5f975936b67cd1bebdd621#file-go-unit-test-setup-and-teardown-math_setup_and_teardown_test-go):

```
func setupSubTest(t *testing.T) func(t *testing.T) {
    t.Log("setup sub test")
    return func(t *testing.T) {
        t.Log("teardown sub test")
    }
}
```

The setup function is in charge of defining and returning the teardown one.

For each test, for instance in a table-driven test scenario:

```
for _, tc := range cases {
    t.Run(tc.name, func(t *testing.T) {
        teardownSubTest := setupSubTest(t)
        defer teardownSubTest(t)

        result := Sum(tc.a, tc.b)
        if result != tc.expected {
            t.Fatalf("expected sum %v, but got %v", tc.expected, result)
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. While it is close to what I want, I was looking for a pre- and post- hooks that will do this automatically, with no chance of forgetting. In python, this is exactly what I used to do, with a simple test runner. But I came to accept that this is not possible in golang.

Comment: +1 I really like this approach, better for readability than having the setup and teardown functions in different places

Comment: I could be mistaken but I don't think the new `T.Cleanup` function added in 1.14 accomplishes what OP wants. I think `T.Cleanup` would still have to be called in each individual test. I think the issue `T.Cleanup` is meant to address is a different issue as described here https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32111

Comment: @ben_frankly it seems like by passing the testing.T into the helper function, you can register the cleanup function directly inside the helper function, thus removing the need to do an extra defer.

Answer (score 2):

If table driven test pattern works for you, you should stick with it. If you need something more generic and flexible feel free to give https://github.com/houqp/gtest a try.

Here is a quick example:

```golang
import (
  "strings"
  "testing"
  "github.com/houqp/gtest"
)

type SampleTests struct{}

// Setup and Teardown are invoked per test group run
func (s *SampleTests) Setup(t *testing.T)      {}
func (s *SampleTests) Teardown(t *testing.T)   {}
// BeforeEach and AfterEach are invoked per test run
func (s *SampleTests) BeforeEach(t *testing.T) {}
func (s *SampleTests) AfterEach(t *testing.T)  {}

func (s *SampleTests) SubTestCompare(t *testing.T) {
  if 1 != 1 {
    t.FailNow()
  }
}

func (s *SampleTests) SubTestCheckPrefix(t *testing.T) {
  if !strings.HasPrefix("abc", "ab") {
    t.FailNow()
  }
}

func TestSampleTests(t *testing.T) {
  gtest.RunSubTests(t, &SampleTests{})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider having a table of functions subTestSetup, subTest and subTestTeardown passing the db connection/other common items in a struct (subTestSetup can return this struct). You can possibly reuse some/parts of the setup & tear down in different functions too & keep this modular as your testing requirement grows. Call defer subTestTeardown() before you call the subTest, to ensure tear down code executes even if there's any issue with subTest.

Answer (score 0):

⚠️ **NOTE: This is not a fully tested solution; it just seems to work very well in casual test scenarios.**

In a simple case, I've used my own implementation of `t.Run()` that does the cleaning after a sub-test has been finished:

```
func Run(t *testing.T, name string, f func(*testing.T)) bool {
    result := t.Run(name, f)
    // Do the cleanup.
    return result
}
```

And in my tests:

```
func TestSomethingWorks(t *testing.T) {
    Run(t, "scenario 1", func(t *testing.T) {
        // ...
    })

    Run(t, "scenario 2", func(t *testing.T) {
        // ...
    })
}
```